# NetworkOnMainThreadException AsyncTask onUIThread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I get the "NetworkOnMainThreadException".. :-(
So..

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this id found
                            // Edit Text

//                            new LoadTextFromJSONToTextViews().execute();
                            // display product data in EditText
                            productDetail1.setText(product.getString(OPTION_ONE));
                            productDetail2.setText(product.getString(OPTION_TWO));
                            productDetail3.setText(product.getString(OPTION_THREE));
                            productDetail4.setText(product.getString(OPTION_FOUR));
                            productDetail5.setText(product.getString(OPTION_FIVE));

                        } else {
                            // product with id not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
```

I know, I do this with the "runOnUiThread", but I have to do this because if not I will become a “Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.” Thats why I put an extra which contains the id of the view which was clicked from the previous activity to this where I want to load the Details of the clicked view. Have anybody an option, how can I solve this without "runOnUIThread"? Thanks for replying :-)

Comment: Move your UI changes into an `onPostExecute()` method on your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: `runOnUiThread` inside `doInBackground` ?!? That is a very interesting approach..

Comment: Look at what you're doing.. You're making a network request inside the runOnUiThread section of your code. This defeats the purpose of Asynctask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 main functions in a AsyncTask, being:

1) onPreExecute
2) doInBackground
3) onPostExecute

You should do all your network communication in doInBackground, as that will be done in the background on a seperate thread.

When you want to update the UI, you do it in onPostExecute (This function is automatically called on the UI thread).

To send information from doInBackground to onPostExecute, you simply return the data in doInBackground by 'return data;', and then it'll be available as a parameter in onPostExecute.

Comment: Sometimes, it can be such easy!
I put the UI changes in the onPost and it works fine! Thanks for the fast replying! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do anything on ui,then you should use onPostExecute() method.
Add your code in onPostExecute() method.
From doInBackground(),just change the value of success variable...and use that in onPostExecute() for your if condition.

Comment: You mean `onPostExecute()`. There's no `onPost()` method in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(), onProgressUpdate() runs UI Thread. 
you can update ui this methods.

but doInBackground() runs non-ui Thread. don't update ui elements.

I modified your code.

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

        // getting product details by making HTTP request
        // Note that product details url will use GET request
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

        // check your log for json response
        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());
        return json;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    int success;
    if(result!=null){
        try{
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                JSONArray productObj = result
                        .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array
                // get first product object from JSON Array
                product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                // product with this id found
                // Edit Text
                // display product data in EditText
                productDetail1.setText(product.getString(OPTION_ONE));
                productDetail2.setText(product.getString(OPTION_TWO));
                productDetail3.setText(product.getString(OPTION_THREE));
                productDetail4.setText(product.getString(OPTION_FOUR));
                productDetail5.setText(product.getString(OPTION_FIVE));
            }else{

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

for understanding AsyncTask, read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you touch the Main UI Thread with these codes:

```
// display product data in EditText
productDetail1.setText(product.getString(OPTION_ONE));
productDetail2.setText(product.getString(OPTION_TWO));
productDetail3.setText(product.getString(OPTION_THREE));
productDetail4.setText(product.getString(OPTION_FOUR));
productDetail5.setText(product.getString(OPTION_FIVE));
```

So you put only them in the `runOnUiThread` as:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    (...)

    if (success == 1) {
        // successfully received product details
        JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

        // get first product object from JSON Array
        product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

        // product with this id found
        // Edit Text

        // new LoadTextFromJSONToTextViews().execute();
        // display product data in EditText
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // display product data in EditText
                productDetail1.setText(product.getString(OPTION_ONE));
                productDetail2.setText(product.getString(OPTION_TWO));
                productDetail3.setText(product.getString(OPTION_THREE));
                productDetail4.setText(product.getString(OPTION_FOUR));
                productDetail5.setText(product.getString(OPTION_FIVE));
            }
        });
    } else {

    (...)
```